# In Rock and Rule, was the demon intended to be a Homo sapiens?

Tags: rock-and-rule

Re-watching *Rock & Rule*, I was struck by how the demon was designed. This is a world where mankind wiped itself out in nuclear fire and the radiation spurred the development of intelligence and civilization in rodents. If their relative sizes did not change, then that would make the size of the demon roughly akin to that of a fully grown human. But while the shape of the demon was humanoid, so are all the rodents in the movie.

[image: image of demon]

Maybe I’m reading into this too much, but was the idea that Mok was summoning a human as a demon, the ancient enemy of rodents? Taking this a step further, perhaps the idea is that this is just how rodents view humans, as these demonic horrors.

Image taken from [here](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/villains/images/5/5b/The_Demon-1-.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140922133821).

Comment: Just a note, you should be able to create tags yourself if one doesn't exist for the work yet. I have done this now.